# Why is my array undefined in main when the class headers are included?

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers

So here is the main where i'm trying to call the array by a pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Lottery.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "LotteryData.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Player player;
    Lottery random;
    LotteryData data;
    player.Input();
    random.setRandomNumber();
    data.PassInfo(int (&Numbers)[6][6]);   

}
```

Apparently "Numbers" is undefined even though the header is included, here's the header and .cpp files relating to it.

LotteryData.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Lottery.h"
#include "Player.h"
using namespace std;

class LotteryData
{
    private:

    public:
    LotteryData();
    ~LotteryData();
    void PassInfo(int (&Numbers)[6][6]);
};
```

LotteryData.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "LotteryData.h"
using namespace std;

LotteryData::LotteryData()
{
}

LotteryData::~LotteryData()
{
}

void LotteryData::PassInfo(int (&Numbers)[6][6])
{
    int* ptr;
    FILE *Numfile;
    Numfile = fopen("C:/Num.txt", "wb");
    ptr = &Numbers[6][6];
    for (int i=0; i<36; i++)
    {
        fwrite(ptr, sizeof(int), 36*36, Numfile);
    }
    fclose(Numfile);
    //ofstream out("Numbers.txt");

}
```

Everything seems fine, I'm puzzled why the reference in the main says the array is undefined, any ideas?

edit: Apologies, missed some bits

Player.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Player
{
    private:

    public:
    Player();
    ~Player();
    void Input(); 
    int Numbers[6][6];
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Player.h"
using namespace std;

Player::Player()
{

}

Player::~Player()
{

}

void Player::Input()
{
    int num(0);
    int duplicate = 0;
    int game = 0;
    int NumberofGames = 0;

    cout<<"How many games do you want to play for this weeks draw?"<<endl;
    cin>>NumberofGames;
    if (NumberofGames>6)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter an amount between 1 and 6"<<endl;
        cin>>NumberofGames;
    }

    do
    {

        for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Number "<< (i+1) <<endl;
            cin>>num;

            if (num > 0 && num <67)
            {
                Numbers[game][i]= num;
            }
            else
            {
                cout <<"Please enter number between 1 and 66"<<endl;
                i = i-1;
            }

        }
        game = game + 1;
        NumberofGames = NumberofGames - 1;

    }
    while (NumberofGames=0);
}
```

Comment: Wait what, why would Numbers be defined o_O?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't in fact see `Numbers` defined anywhere in your code... where do you think its definition is?

Comment: @DavidNorris `void LotteryData::PassInfo(int (&Numbers)[6][6])`, But it doesn't do what he thinks it does.

Comment: @andre What Zac said in his answer below... that's not a declaration of `Numbers`.

Comment: @user2288204 Do you have c++11 available? I would suggest using `std::array<std::array<int, 6>, 6>`

Comment: Sorry, just added in the rest of the code I missed by mistake. Hopefully that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a `Player` has an array called "Numbers".

Then you would use it like this:

```
data.PassInfo(player.Numbers);
```

Comment: @user2288204 Good. Now you need to repair the `fwrite` loop, as it is seriously broken.

Comment: Just noticed the fwrite loop doesn't even print anything, just creates the file, though I'm stuck on how to fix it. Can you point out the things I'm obviously missing? :)

Comment: @user2288204 You're writing 1296 ints from outside the array (its last element is `Elements[5][5]`) and you're writing that same non-existing thing 36 times. That is very undefined behaviour (so anything can happen).

Answer (score 2):

```
void PassInfo(int (&Numbers)[6][6]);
```

That line does not declare an array - it declares a function.  You have no declaration for an array in your class (in fact, you have no data members declared in your class at all).

If you want to declare a member array, you need to modify your class definition:

```
class LotteryData
{
private:
        int Numbers[6][6]; // this declares an array
public:
    LotteryData();
    ~LotteryData();
    void PassInfo(int (&arr)[6][6]); // this is still a function declaration
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because you made a function's parameter be named `Numbers` doesn't magically mean that your program has an array called `Numbers` declared in it.

Answer (score 1):

In your main() function,

```
data.PassInfo(int (&Numbers)[6][6]);
```

This is wrong. You should simply pass a reference to 2D array.

```
int (&Numbers)[6][6];
data.PassInfo(Numbers);
```